# Encrypt data with public key

Tags: windows-phone-7, encryption, public-key-encryption

i need to encrypt my symmetric key which is in AES with my public key. I take my public key from server's certificate but i don't know how to encrypt my symmetric key with this public key in Windows Phone 7, i cannot use X509Certificate2. I don't know how to make that RSACryptoServiceProvider to use this public key to encrypt data? Please Help me!

Answer (score 2):

There is a discussion on another forum about this, I hope this will aid you in your quest!

[Working With X509Cert on WP7](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/windowsphone7series/thread/3061aaf8-f644-4fc0-887e-19e22c2fe021)

Comment: Thnx Claus for your reply, but doesn't help me